# TFS Changing Work Item Priority Field Randomly

Tags: workflow, workitem

I am using TFS2012 and I have found a strange issue that happens in only a couple of cases when using Excel to update the TFS work items. For some reason, a work item's priority is randomly assigned the value of 2 when ever another field is changed. I have been able to reproduce it when using excel but nothing more. 
I am starting to suspect some sort of setting in the backlog configuration or in the project common configuration despite already extracting the project's common config. I have also checked the work item workflows and i do not see any issues with them

Anyone know what might be a possible cause for this issue?

Comment: Do you have an event service that might be listening for changed work items which changes the field value?

Comment: Alicia, we do not have any events or triggers for that condition. I have noticed that it only happens on old work items. Currently our latest work Item ID is in the one hundred thousand, this occurs for items in the sixty thousand or lower ID range.

Comment: @Alicia, I think I found the issue. For some reason we have started seeing this issue appear more often and I believe it's because something was run against the TFS databases. Specifically against the dbo.workitemslatest table. After cracking my head for hours, I looked at dbo.workitemslatest and dbo.workitemsare on the DB and the priority field Fld10010 does not match for both tables, which I assume needs to be the same in both tables.